# can not reach first bit of char in c

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit

I am trying to access the first bit of char with the code below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        char *a = argv[1];
        printf("%d ", (128 & (a[0]))>>7);
        putc('\n',stdout);
        return 0;
}
```

but for any input it's output `0`. What's wrong with my bitwise operators?

---

Comment: Are you only using ASCII characters as input?

Comment: Which is the "first bit"? The mask `0x80` isolates the 8th bit (bit 7). Please show the *particular* input - how you run the program. You are not testing `argc`.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz yes

Comment: @Amir reza Riahi All characters are positive?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you mean I should use unsigned char?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi I mean that if you are using ASCII characters then it seems all of them have positive values. That is the sign bit is equal to 0.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I mean the most significant bit (biggest one I thinks)

Comment: It is never set, signed or unsigned. ASCII is < 128. Mask is `10000000b` data max is `01111111b`.

Comment: For which characters do you expect it to be non-zero?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz if I use unsigned char instead does it will get non-zero?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I tested 6, but again give 0

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Because your mask position has changed too. See if this is what you want: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1BDoIwFETX9BQ/GKVtqoHEsEF7EWTx0yI0wY@prRujV690N/PeJGOOZkGaUto5Mku0I1xewbr1NGvmKMADHfEcjAIzo5cS/fQWH1bkBhLhCpn0zdCx4um36Z2XewulAt6e4QDY14PQuhXZx2B4daNKbSdrDJn5MURPUHfsm1L6/QE "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I know it's irrelevant but for base64, should I use the sign bit for encoding or not?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi I don't think that question makes sense. If you have another question, please just ask another question. It's hard to help when you don't answer people who are asking you for clarification.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I  looked comments, as I see I've answered your questions. But if I forgot to answer one of your questions, I'm sorry. It was my neglect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the size of a `char` is 1 byte, witch means its range of representation is from `0` to `255` in unsigned decimal values.

Once the first bit normally is the most significant, the result of your program should be `1` for the input of a value between `128` and `255`.

In order to test if the operation `(128 & (a[0]))>>7)` is correct, I built another program that iterates between `0` and `255` and prints in `stdout` the result of this operation applied to each value.

Here is the source code.

```
/* program.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        printf("Code: %d; First bit: %d\n", i, (128 & i) >> 7);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the result.

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o program program.c
$ ./program
Code: 0; First bit: 0
Code: 1; First bit: 0
Code: 2; First bit: 0
Code: 3; First bit: 0
Code: 4; First bit: 0
Code: 5; First bit: 0
Code: 6; First bit: 0
Code: 7; First bit: 0
Code: 8; First bit: 0
Code: 9; First bit: 0
Code: 10; First bit: 0
Code: 11; First bit: 0
Code: 12; First bit: 0
Code: 13; First bit: 0
Code: 14; First bit: 0
Code: 15; First bit: 0
Code: 16; First bit: 0
Code: 17; First bit: 0
Code: 18; First bit: 0
Code: 19; First bit: 0
Code: 20; First bit: 0
Code: 21; First bit: 0
Code: 22; First bit: 0
Code: 23; First bit: 0
Code: 24; First bit: 0
Code: 25; First bit: 0
Code: 26; First bit: 0
Code: 27; First bit: 0
Code: 28; First bit: 0
Code: 29; First bit: 0
Code: 30; First bit: 0
Code: 31; First bit: 0
Code: 32; First bit: 0
Code: 33; First bit: 0
Code: 34; First bit: 0
Code: 35; First bit: 0
Code: 36; First bit: 0
Code: 37; First bit: 0
Code: 38; First bit: 0
Code: 39; First bit: 0
Code: 40; First bit: 0
Code: 41; First bit: 0
Code: 42; First bit: 0
Code: 43; First bit: 0
Code: 44; First bit: 0
Code: 45; First bit: 0
Code: 46; First bit: 0
Code: 47; First bit: 0
Code: 48; First bit: 0
Code: 49; First bit: 0
Code: 50; First bit: 0
Code: 51; First bit: 0
Code: 52; First bit: 0
Code: 53; First bit: 0
Code: 54; First bit: 0
Code: 55; First bit: 0
Code: 56; First bit: 0
Code: 57; First bit: 0
Code: 58; First bit: 0
Code: 59; First bit: 0
Code: 60; First bit: 0
Code: 61; First bit: 0
Code: 62; First bit: 0
Code: 63; First bit: 0
Code: 64; First bit: 0
Code: 65; First bit: 0
Code: 66; First bit: 0
Code: 67; First bit: 0
Code: 68; First bit: 0
Code: 69; First bit: 0
Code: 70; First bit: 0
Code: 71; First bit: 0
Code: 72; First bit: 0
Code: 73; First bit: 0
Code: 74; First bit: 0
Code: 75; First bit: 0
Code: 76; First bit: 0
Code: 77; First bit: 0
Code: 78; First bit: 0
Code: 79; First bit: 0
Code: 80; First bit: 0
Code: 81; First bit: 0
Code: 82; First bit: 0
Code: 83; First bit: 0
Code: 84; First bit: 0
Code: 85; First bit: 0
Code: 86; First bit: 0
Code: 87; First bit: 0
Code: 88; First bit: 0
Code: 89; First bit: 0
Code: 90; First bit: 0
Code: 91; First bit: 0
Code: 92; First bit: 0
Code: 93; First bit: 0
Code: 94; First bit: 0
Code: 95; First bit: 0
Code: 96; First bit: 0
Code: 97; First bit: 0
Code: 98; First bit: 0
Code: 99; First bit: 0
Code: 100; First bit: 0
Code: 101; First bit: 0
Code: 102; First bit: 0
Code: 103; First bit: 0
Code: 104; First bit: 0
Code: 105; First bit: 0
Code: 106; First bit: 0
Code: 107; First bit: 0
Code: 108; First bit: 0
Code: 109; First bit: 0
Code: 110; First bit: 0
Code: 111; First bit: 0
Code: 112; First bit: 0
Code: 113; First bit: 0
Code: 114; First bit: 0
Code: 115; First bit: 0
Code: 116; First bit: 0
Code: 117; First bit: 0
Code: 118; First bit: 0
Code: 119; First bit: 0
Code: 120; First bit: 0
Code: 121; First bit: 0
Code: 122; First bit: 0
Code: 123; First bit: 0
Code: 124; First bit: 0
Code: 125; First bit: 0
Code: 126; First bit: 0
Code: 127; First bit: 0
Code: 128; First bit: 1
Code: 129; First bit: 1
Code: 130; First bit: 1
Code: 131; First bit: 1
Code: 132; First bit: 1
Code: 133; First bit: 1
Code: 134; First bit: 1
Code: 135; First bit: 1
Code: 136; First bit: 1
Code: 137; First bit: 1
Code: 138; First bit: 1
Code: 139; First bit: 1
Code: 140; First bit: 1
Code: 141; First bit: 1
Code: 142; First bit: 1
Code: 143; First bit: 1
Code: 144; First bit: 1
Code: 145; First bit: 1
Code: 146; First bit: 1
Code: 147; First bit: 1
Code: 148; First bit: 1
Code: 149; First bit: 1
Code: 150; First bit: 1
Code: 151; First bit: 1
Code: 152; First bit: 1
Code: 153; First bit: 1
Code: 154; First bit: 1
Code: 155; First bit: 1
Code: 156; First bit: 1
Code: 157; First bit: 1
Code: 158; First bit: 1
Code: 159; First bit: 1
Code: 160; First bit: 1
Code: 161; First bit: 1
Code: 162; First bit: 1
Code: 163; First bit: 1
Code: 164; First bit: 1
Code: 165; First bit: 1
Code: 166; First bit: 1
Code: 167; First bit: 1
Code: 168; First bit: 1
Code: 169; First bit: 1
Code: 170; First bit: 1
Code: 171; First bit: 1
Code: 172; First bit: 1
Code: 173; First bit: 1
Code: 174; First bit: 1
Code: 175; First bit: 1
Code: 176; First bit: 1
Code: 177; First bit: 1
Code: 178; First bit: 1
Code: 179; First bit: 1
Code: 180; First bit: 1
Code: 181; First bit: 1
Code: 182; First bit: 1
Code: 183; First bit: 1
Code: 184; First bit: 1
Code: 185; First bit: 1
Code: 186; First bit: 1
Code: 187; First bit: 1
Code: 188; First bit: 1
Code: 189; First bit: 1
Code: 190; First bit: 1
Code: 191; First bit: 1
Code: 192; First bit: 1
Code: 193; First bit: 1
Code: 194; First bit: 1
Code: 195; First bit: 1
Code: 196; First bit: 1
Code: 197; First bit: 1
Code: 198; First bit: 1
Code: 199; First bit: 1
Code: 200; First bit: 1
Code: 201; First bit: 1
Code: 202; First bit: 1
Code: 203; First bit: 1
Code: 204; First bit: 1
Code: 205; First bit: 1
Code: 206; First bit: 1
Code: 207; First bit: 1
Code: 208; First bit: 1
Code: 209; First bit: 1
Code: 210; First bit: 1
Code: 211; First bit: 1
Code: 212; First bit: 1
Code: 213; First bit: 1
Code: 214; First bit: 1
Code: 215; First bit: 1
Code: 216; First bit: 1
Code: 217; First bit: 1
Code: 218; First bit: 1
Code: 219; First bit: 1
Code: 220; First bit: 1
Code: 221; First bit: 1
Code: 222; First bit: 1
Code: 223; First bit: 1
Code: 224; First bit: 1
Code: 225; First bit: 1
Code: 226; First bit: 1
Code: 227; First bit: 1
Code: 228; First bit: 1
Code: 229; First bit: 1
Code: 230; First bit: 1
Code: 231; First bit: 1
Code: 232; First bit: 1
Code: 233; First bit: 1
Code: 234; First bit: 1
Code: 235; First bit: 1
Code: 236; First bit: 1
Code: 237; First bit: 1
Code: 238; First bit: 1
Code: 239; First bit: 1
Code: 240; First bit: 1
Code: 241; First bit: 1
Code: 242; First bit: 1
Code: 243; First bit: 1
Code: 244; First bit: 1
Code: 245; First bit: 1
Code: 246; First bit: 1
Code: 247; First bit: 1
Code: 248; First bit: 1
Code: 249; First bit: 1
Code: 250; First bit: 1
Code: 251; First bit: 1
Code: 252; First bit: 1
Code: 253; First bit: 1
Code: 254; First bit: 1
Code: 255; First bit: 1
$
```

As expected, the result was `0` between `0` and `127` and `1` between `128` and `255`.

Comment: There are no ASCII codes above 127. ASCII codes go from 0 to 127. If a C implementation has character codes above 127, it is using something other than ASCII (possibly in addition to ASCII).

Comment: @Miguel Carvalho The type char can behave as the type signed char. It means that the range of ;positive values is 0 - 127.

Comment: Most probably you are using unicode, where `«` is [LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ab/index.htm) which are two bytes `0xC2 0xAB` in utf-8. In bash shell you can be explicit with C-ish quoting `./program $'\xff'` . The "Extended ASCII" depends on the codepage, ex. in WINDOWS-1255 « is 171. I doubt you are using windows-125* on linux. Check with `strlen(argv[1])` in your program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, your are right. In fact, a `char` type in C represents an character encoded in extended ASCII, witch range is from `0` to `255`. I already edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: A `char` type in C represents a character encoding in **whatever encoding the implementation chooses**, with certain requirements stated in the C standard, such as that members of the basic execution character set must be nonnegative. A C implementation does not have to use ASCII at all; it may use EBCDIC or other encodings.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, in fact, a `char` behaves as a signed value. What I meant to say is that the range of numbers of a char is from `00000000` to `11111111` in binary, witch its equivalent to `0` from `255` or `-128` to `127`. But instead of "positive numbers" I should've said "unsigned values". Thank you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i did not knew ASCII was't universal. I always thought the other larger and modern encoding were an extension of ASCII. After some research done, I realized I was wrong and I edited my original answer according to what was mentioned here. Thank you.

Comment: @KamilCuk I did not knew ASCII was't universal. I always thought the other larger and modern encoding were an extension of ASCII. After some research done, I realized I was wrong and I edited my original answer according to what was mentioned here. Thank you.